# Entry into France

Tags: schengen-visas, france, borders

I have obtained a French work visa with a start date of 1 June 2022 but I have already entered Europe via Finland in the middle of May, using my Australian passport which allows me to be here without a visa for up to three months.

When I switch to my French visa on 1 June 2022, am I allowed to enter France from another Schengen country or do I have to leave the Schengen area at the end of May and enter France officially from outside the Schengen on 1 June 2022?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This probably belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Have you been issued a short-stay (C) or a long-stay (D) visa?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Australian citizens are not normally issued short-stay visas.

Comment: And now it is there: [Entry into France](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24206/2440).  I would encourage those who upvoted this question to join me in upvoting that one.